# How can I add an image in Hugo in home page?

Tags: go, hugo

I'm trying to show a photo on home page in _index.md file

```
---
title: Home
---
**Title**  
Text is here

![flutter image](/images/home_flutter.png)
```

I added code from hugo documetation in baseof.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    {{ partial "meta.html" . }}
    {{ $image := resources.Get "images/home_flutter.png" }}
</head>

<body>
    <header>{{partial "nav.html" . }}</header>
 {{ block "main" . }}
 
 {{ end }}
 {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
<footer>
</html>
```

The photo is in assets/images folder.

logo.svg file on web page works. in this code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/"><img src={{  (resources.GetMatch "images/logo.svg" | resources.ExecuteAsTemplate "logo.svg" "nothing").Permalink }} alt="logo", height="80em"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/what_we_offer/">What We Offer</a></li>
      <li><a href="/who_we_are/">Who We Are</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="/careers/">Careers</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

I think if logo.svg works on this way, then home_flutter.png should work too. and for testing I changed it like this:

```
<li><a href="/"><img src={{  (resources.GetMatch "images/home_flutter.png" | resources.ExecuteAsTemplate "home_flutter.png" "nothing").Permalink }} alt="logo", height="80em"></a></li>
```

But it shows me error:

```
Error: error building site: EXECUTE-AS-TEMPLATE: failed to transform "images/photo.png" (image/png): failed to parse Resource "images/home_flutter.png" as Template:: template: images/home_flutter.png:177: unrecognized character in action: U+FFFD '�'
```

How can I solve this problem? Is this code in right place in baseof.html?

```
{{ $image := resources.Get "images/home_flutter.png" }}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in the static folder instead of the assets folder and remove this:

```
{{ $image := resources.Get "images/home_flutter.png" }}
```